# Wix launch application window is hidden

Tags: wix

I've got an MSI installer built with Wix, and as is common I want a tickbox on the Finished page to launch the app. I've followed the method here to do this: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/ui_and_localization/run_program_after_install.html

It works, but the problem is the application window is hidden by any other windows that are on the screen, when it starts up it doesn't show at the front. I don't know why this is happening? Is there a way to fix this, or do I have to create another custom action to bring the window to the front?